# How is load->store reordering possible with in-order commit -- follow up

Tags: cpu-architecture, memory-barriers

I would like to ask for some clarification about what discussed in this thread [How is load->store reordering possible with in-order commit ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52215031/how-is-load-store-reordering-possible-with-in-order-commit) -- sorry I've not enough reputation to add comments directly there.

> A load can't fault after you've checked the TLB and/or whatever
> memory-region stuff for it. That part has to be complete before it
> retires, or before it reaches the end of an in-order pipeline. Just
> like a retired store sitting in the store buffer waiting to commit, a
> retired load sitting in a load buffer is definitely happening at some
> point.
>
> So the sequence on an in-order pipeline is:
>
> `lw  r0, [r1]` TLB hit, but misses in L1d cache. Load execution unit writes the address (`r1`) into a load buffer. Any later instruction that tries to read `r0` will stall, but we know for sure that the load didn't fault.
>
> With `r0` tied to waiting for that load buffer to be ready, the `lw` instruction itself can leave the pipeline (retire), and so can later
> instructions.

So you're basically saying that `lw` instruction (or its micro-op) can retire even though, after it retires, the load itself can stay 'in flight' inside the load buffer (load queue) waiting for the data arrive from somewhere.

> `sw  r2, [r3]` store execution unit writes address + data to the store buffer / queue. Then this instruction can retire.
>
> **Probing the load buffers finds that this store doesn't overlap with the pending load, so it can commit to L1d.** (If it *had* overlapped, you couldn't commit it until a MESI RFO completed anyway, and fast restart would forward the incoming data to the load buffer).

Here you are saying that when the store executes (or actually after it retires ?) it will search inside the load buffer to check if there is any *older* in-flight load waiting for data that happen to overlap with that store's target address.

Does it make sense ? Thank you.

Comment: upvoted, hopefully I or someone can figure out what I was thinking of 3 years ago.  I'd have to re-read my full answer, but it sounds a bit odd.  (Also I should probably update it to use ARM instead of MIPS mnemonics, to go with the ARM register names :P)