# how best to ensure that pointer has been read into register, for benchmarking purposes?

Tags: rust, cpu-architecture, benchmarking, microbenchmark

I have some code roughly like this

```
unsafe fn foo(p: *const X) {
  let x = *p;
  let begin = Instant::now();
  ... // potentially expensive processing of x
  let duration = begin.elapsed();
}
```

The issue is that due to out-of-order execution, etc., `duration` will generally include the time spent waiting for `p` to be read from memory. I have reasons to want to benchmark the "potentially expensive processing" *without* including that waiting time. What can I do? Is this the place for memory barriers/fences? (note that I'm only concerned with single-threaded execution here)

Comment: If the code under test i so short that cache-miss latency would be relevant, timing overhead is also a significant problem, and the timed interval might be shorter than the CPU's out-of-order exec window (hundreds of instructions).  Usually it's best to create a loop that measures either throughput or latency of the code under test.  (Independent `x` values, or an `x` that depends on the computation result from the previous `x`, respectively.)  [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987)

Comment: On x86, probably `lfence` after the load would do the trick; x86 CPUs require the data to arrive before a load can retire from the back-end (*[How is load->store reordering possible with in-order commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52215031)*), and `lfence` is also an execution-order barrier, draining the ROB (reorder buffer) before later instructions can start executing, or in practice before they can even issue from the front-end into the back-end.  (Weakly-ordered ISAs can let loads retire while the data's still in flight, but then load-load fences aren't no-ops and are prob. sufficient.)

Comment: Did you have a particular architecture in mind?  There probably isn't a portable way to do this.  For example on x86, none of the standard C++ `atomic_thread_fence` orders would compile to `lfence`, because it's a no-op as far as memory ordering is concerned, except I think with NT loads from WC memory.  It is also a speculation barrier, though, for Spectre mitigation, so I could imagine something exposing that portably.