# about _mm_clflush (void const* p)

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, x86, cpu-cache

I have 2 thread bonded to 2 cpu core separately.

thread A and thread B have the same cache line data.

If I modified the cache line data and call _mm_clflush (void const* p) in thread A.

The cache line (L1,L2,L3) in thread B will become invalid and only can be read from main memory again.

Is that right ?

Comment: yes; the store in thread A will invalidate core B's copy of it, and clflush will invalidate all copies including in L3, so thread A has to re-read from RAM, not L3 or any kind of direct transfer between cores (on microarchitectures that can do that.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes.

According to the Intel documentation, the `CLFLUSH` instruction invalidates the cache line in the entire "cache coherency domain". It is therefore not limited to the shared cache (normally Level 3 Cache), but also affects the dedicated cache of all other CPUs (i.e. their Level 1 and Level 2 Cache).

So, the next time a read takes place from that cache line, it will have to be read from main memory again.

Comment: x86 loads are strongly ordered; a speculative early load will cause a memory-order mis-speculation if the line is invalidated before the core is architecturally allowed to have read the line.  (memory-order mis-speculation:  [Why flush the pipeline for Memory Order Violation caused by other logical processors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55563077)).  Putting any kind of barrier before a load would be pointless unless you're blocking local StoreLoad reordering wrt. earlier stores in that thread/core.  (and HW prefetch is just into cache, where it's still coherent and can still be invalidated)

Comment: I have temporarily removed the disputed paragraph. I will look into it tomorrow.